# Is "narcotraffic" a real word?

Tags: word-usage, is-it-a-word

I know the meaning but does this word actually exist in English? Should I use it in a formal paper?

Comment: Seems perfectly cromulent to me.

Comment: It probably is a jargon term in some circles. If you are in them, then it might be acceptable.

Comment: It sounds like a backwards import from Spanish narcotrafico (drug traffic), narcotraficante (drug dealer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Narcotraffic* is obviously a [compound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_word) word. Taking the prefix *[narco-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=narco-)* which is greek for "numbness", but it's clearly, from its common usage, a reference to narcotics. *Traffic* is form Italian (*trafficare*), meaning "carry on trade", and may trace back to Latin, but the relationship in meaning becomes less obvious at that point.

(To be pedantic about it, if we assume *traffic* is Latin, it's a [hybrid word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_word), because it combines a greek prefix with a latin root.)

> Although there is no universally agreed-upon guideline regarding the use of compound words in the English language, in recent decades written English has displayed a noticeable trend towards increased use of compounds. (from [compound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_word))

You should consider it safe for a formal paper if you have found it to be widely used already. You can find several publications ([ref](https://www.google.com/search?q=narcotraffic&biw=1440&bih=764&tbm=bks&ei=wz0nU7LDBsHX2AXcpoAI&start=0&sa=N)) that already use either *narcotraffic* or *narco-traffic*. (To answer whether the hypen should be used, see [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/157905/anti-followed-by-phrase-usage-of-hyphen).)

Comment: it's trafficare, not "trafficarre", I'm Italian ;-)

Comment: Ops! E sono facilmente distratto! Grazie.